# Can I use a NAS Hard drive into a portable USB hard drive enclosure and then still use it in the NAS?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, raid, nas

I am digitizing my movie collection and by the time I am done I estimate that I will need 30-40 TB of space. I plan on setting up a NAS 6 bay system with enough space to save all my media as well as RAID it for backup. I cannot afford the NAS and all the drives immediately, but I have already begin to digitize my collection and would like to keep going until I have enough money for the whole system.

I need more hard drive space now because I have almost used up all of my computer and external drive space. However, I don't want to buy temporary external drives to keep digitizing for now and then not need them once I have a NAS setup.

So my main question is can I buy a 10TB NAS hard drive, such as the Seagate Ironwolf 10 TB NAS internal drive and use some sort of connection to use it as a USB drive, then use it in my NAS setup in the future when I purchase it. I figured it would be more economical to buy hard drives that I can use now and then integrate them into a NAS setup (I plan on getting the Synology DS1618+) later.

Comment: Depending on how you set it up in the NAS, specifically if you configure it as RAID, then all data on the disk will be effectively erased. It is not a trivial operation to change  to RAID or between RAID types. Just putting the disk into the NAS *may* work but then you will just have a bunch of disks in an enclosure which may be annoying to manage. At the very least you should have an *actual* backup of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. First of all, RAID is not a backup. RAID is redundancy, but if a file is deleted, corrupted or changed inappropriately, it is gone forever.

With that out of the way, no, you cannot put data on a drive and then add it in to a NAS and continue to use the data on it.

You can buy hard drives and add them to a NAS to expand the storage later. But, you will need to start with a working NAS setup and expand from there.

The NAS will require the drive to be erased in order to add it in to the storage array. Therefore, if you choose to put data on a USB drive you will need to move the data somewhere else before adding the drive to the storage array.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That is what I figured, but needed clarification. Looks like I will need to buy lots of external hard drives until I can afford the setup I need.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with parts of @appleodity answer but I can see where he is coming from.

From a hardware POV, you absolutely can buy a (SATA) hard drive and put it in a USB enclosure, and then chuck it into a NAS later. From a data-on-the-disk POV, this is unlikely to work. Of-course, you may he able to buy a NAS with another disk, move data to that disk then add the old disk to the array.

Where appleodity and myself strongly AGREE is that a NAS is not backup. A NAS provides resiliancy against drive failure - not theft, deletion or most types of corruption. Also, for the size disks you are using know that RAID5 is no good, and RAID6 is very marginal.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to keep in mind is that raid 0 offers no safety net and is comprised of 1 or more drives, raid 1 and above provides a safety net against drive failure. raid 1 is 2 drives and have the data mirrored across the 2, raid 5 is 3 or more drives where 2 or more are data and 1 is parity, raid 6 is 4 drives minimum where 2 or more drives are data and 2 drives are parity.  Best to study how raid arrays work and understand the cost upfront.